# Shepherd advanceOn with knockout click databinding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using knockout and [Shepherd](https://shepherdjs.dev/docs/index.html) together.
In Shepherd, there is a way to make interactive tour to go to next step like this:

```
 tour.addStep({
//Option....
//If there is a click event on this selector, trigger tour.next
 advanceOn:{selector:"#id", event: "click"},
})
```

But in knockout, I register the click event by data-binding

```
<a id="id" data-bind="click: clickHandler"></a>
```

It does not trigger the advanceOn. I have tried to `return true` inside `clickHandler` to no avai.

The only workaround this to call $("#id").click() inside the handler to trigger advancedOn
Is there a better way?

Comment: why is there any need for a data-bind click ? Does it work if you ommit the data-bind? I guess you are initializing tour before the actual DOM is mutated ?

Comment: Try "mouseup" or "mousedown" events. I had problems with "click" also.